# How to change the time zone in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, timezone

In my database table field I am taking the date time value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Then I am not getting current time of my country. So how can I change the time zone as ('Asia/Kolkata') for a MySQL database.

I have access to manage database with phpMyAdmin.

I think my database is located in US and I am using codeigniter to develop my site.

Comment: Just an FYI, phpMyAdmin is the front end for managing the database not the database itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, try to use `sysdate();`

Comment: How can i use sysdate() function in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00'");
```

http://www.worldtimezone.com/time-usa12.php

Insert correct time zone.

Comment: where I will put this query. Sorry I am very new to PHP and codeiginiter

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay. Let me test it